# Tea bags to find the leak on the International Space Station?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, russian-segment, leak

Katya Pavlushchenko (@katlinegrey)'s [tweet](https://twitter.com/katlinegrey/status/1316774108923867148) says:

> Here’s some of today’s news from the ISS. First of all, the leak was finally found (thanks to the tea bag). Anatoly Ivanishin sent photos to the Mission Control Center, which shows how the tea leaves accumulated around what he believed was a scratch.
>
> https://ria.ru/20201015/mks-1579976642.html

Per [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41018/12102) I understand that something like duct tape was used during the mitigation and/or repair of the Soyuz MS-09 leak at the ISS in 2018, **but** ***tea bags?***

---

Chris Hadfield's 2018 [tweet](https://twitter.com/Cmdr_Hadfield/status/1035289238873550848)

> When your spaceship suddenly starts leaking air, you fix the hole with duct tape & a gob of epoxy. Nice save, @Space_Station crew!

Comment: I guess the theory is to float particles in the air and wait for the flow into drive them to the leaking point. Ground tea leaves seems to be an OK choice if they don't have any other specialized material. Same thing as in a ship or submarine you use milk to mark waterflow.

Comment: To be honest I was more surprised they have tea bags and not condensed or powdered tea. Which country has such high standards for fresh tea that went ahead and designed a space tea pot? Not the Chinese for sure.

Comment: @user3528438 It's actually called the ISSpresso, by Lavazzo, and it's capable of making espresso, tea, and broth. It was sent up in 2015 by, rather predictably, the Italian Space Agency. Clearly, you can go to orbit, but going without good espresso is unthinkable. I believe the coffee grounds or tea leaves are normally kept in those little sealed mylar packets similar to a Kcup or the thingies a Mars Flavia uses, so they likely had to cut open one of those packets to get at the dry tea leaves.

Comment: It looks like the ISSpresso may have been removed a couple years ago, but I'm sure they still have a packet-based system for making fresh hot drinks like tea and coffee out of the hot water supply, so the answer stands even if they aren't using that specific machine anymore.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I've just asked [Can they still make espresso on the ISS? If so, with what?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48034/12102)

Comment: Epoxy and duct tape makes perfect sense, epoxy to seal it and duct tape to keep the epoxy where it needs to be.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica indeed, other answers on that page show quite a number of duct tape sightings!

Comment: @user3528438 At this point I'm completely sure if not for the ISSpresso, Russians would have designed and sent a space samovar. Just to give you a clue, on all long distance trains (which are the vast majority of trains in Russia) there's a samovar for the passengers in every single train car.

Comment: @SF The samovar on the ISS has existed from the very beginning. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40483/how-do-astronauts-brew-tea-on-iss-and-what-brewing-temperature-is-common

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Media reports about the discovery of an air leak on the ISS using a
> tea bag is rubbish, according to Russian cosmonaut Pavel Vinogradov.
> In an interview with Gazeta.Ru, he said that the journalists had
> misinterpreted the negotiations between the Russian station crew and
> the MCC specialists.
>
> “This is rubbish. Nothing was found with any tea bags. Here, of
> course, they went too far. This is the nonsense that our media
> broadcast. About the nonsense can only be regretted. Ivanishin told about a different
> story. He spoke the language that all specialists understand him.
> Someone, somewhere, heard something wrong, and then fables began to
> spread, ”Vinogradov said.

Translated from:

> Сообщения об обнаружении утечки воздуха на МКС с помощью чайного пакетика – это белиберда, считает российский космонавт Павел Виноградов. В беседе с «Газетой.Ru» он заявил, что журналисты неправильно интерпретировали переговоры российского экипажа станции со специалистами ЦУПа.
>
> «Это белиберда. Никакими чайными пакетиками ничего не обнаруживали.
> Тут, конечно, перегнули. Это глупость, которую транслируют наши СМИ. О
> ней можно только сожалеть. Иванишин рассказывал о другой истории. Он
> говорил на том языке, на котором его понимают все специалисты. Кто-то
> где-то не так услышал, и вот пошли небылицы», — сказал Виноградов.

https://www.gazeta.ru/social/news/2020/10/15/n_15085903.shtml

P.S. I found the [full quote](https://tass.ru/kosmos/9724669) and it is contradictory:

Phrase # 1 that the contents of the tea bag were scattered in the Zvezda module.

> "Мы думаем, мы действительно идентифицировали вероятное место утечки.
> Мы распределили пакетик чая (в модуле "Звезда" - прим. ТАСС) перед
> закрытием переходной камеры", - сказал Анатолий Иванишин.

Phrase # 2 that a [plastic] bag of tea flew like a "balloon blown by the wind".

> "У нас есть несколько фото и видео направления, в котором полетел пакетик с чаем или куда намеревался полететь, что как раз показывает, в каком направлении дует воздух из возможного места утечки", - уточнил космонавт.

Comment: Has anyone said in detail what it was actually about?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It sounds like someone simply *used an analogy* during a discussion, and no actual tea bags were harmed in the making of this news story?

Comment: @ikrase Alas. There is no original audio recording of the negotiations between the cosmonauts and the Mission Control Center.

Comment: @uhoh The original source of this news is unknown. If an audio recording was available, then one could understand what it was about.

Comment: This reminds me *a little bit* of [Which ISRO satellite was built in 24 hours?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27232/12102)

Comment: Damn, so we can't add "reading the tea leaves" to the superstitions in space question....

Comment: @uhoh I was able to find that this dialogue was broadcast by NASA. If there are archives of these records somewhere, then it is possible to try to find this dialog.

Comment: Interesting.  That contradicts what I'm getting through official flow downs on my end.

Comment: @Tristan Perhaps this is the difficulties of correct translation. Tea bags on the ISS are not something that everyone is used to seeing on Earth. I guess someone might have suggested inflating the tea bags like balloons and watching them drift.

Comment: @A.Rumlin Could be. That paper they use to make tea bags is pretty light too, so maybe they just used bits of that or something similar?

Comment: @A.Rumlin Science Alert:  [osmonaut Anatoly Ivanishin released a few leaves from a tea bag in the transfer chamber of the Zvezda Service Module the section of the station's Russian segment that houses a kitchen, sleeping quarters, and bathroom. Then the crew sealed the chamber off by closing its hatches, and monitored the tea leaves on video cameras as they floated in microgravity. The leaves slowly floated toward a scratch in the wall near the module's communication equipment...](https://www.sciencealert.com/iss-crew-just-used-floating-tea-leaves-to-find-an-elusive-air-leak)

Comment: links to TASS which seems to say that it was the whole bag: [Russian cosmonauts trace air leak aboard orbital outpost with tea bag; The tea bag’s sway in zero gravity conditions towards the air leak was registered by cameras](https://tass.com/science/1212465#:~:text=Russian%20cosmonauts%20trace%20air%20leak%20aboard%20orbital%20outpost%20with%20tea%20bag,-The%20tea%20bag&%23039;s&amp;text=MOSCOW,%20October%2015.&amp;text=As%20Russia&%23039;s%20State%20Space%20Corporation,the%20crew&%23039;s%20life%20and%20health.)

Comment: I'm still a little confused, but is the final story that *they did use tea leaf particles* as tracers, but did not use the whole bag as a single object?

Comment: Was just coming here to post the TASS link!

Comment: Does TASS call them "Russian cosmonauts" just to emphasize that there are no longer any Soviet cosmonauts?  Or are there still other kinds?

Comment: @uhoh I edited the answer. Quote about both.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune This opposition is "our people" and "strangers" at the orbital station. i.e. americans.